# how do i resolve' as prefix' in flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
The name 'LocationAccuracy' is defined in the libraries 'package:geolocation/geolocation.dart', 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' and 'package:location_platform_interface/location_platform_interface.dart (via package:location/location.dart)'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.dartambiguous_import
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This message is because there's a `LocationAccuracy` defined in more than one library. So you need define from which library you are getting this LocationAccuracy. So you need specify a prefix after the import like this:

```
import 'package:geolocation/geolocation.dart' as geo; // or whatever name you want
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' as geolocator; // or whatever name you want
```

And then you can refer to the specific `LocationAccuracy` you want to use in this way:

`geo.LocationAccuracy` or
`geolocator.LocationAccuracy`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the second suggestion of hiding LocationAccuracy by adding this after importing 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' like this:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' hide LocationAccuracy;
```