# Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports

Tags: flutter, dart

I made custom widget 'AppBarTheme' in appBar.dart and I want to use it as appBar in home_page.dart but It has an error like the subject above. How can I work arrange this?

--appBar.dart

```
class AppBarTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarTheme({Key? key, required Color backgroundColor, required List<Chip> actions, required Icon leading}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.home_filled,
        size: 40,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      actions: [
        Chip(label: Text('\$${ego}'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

--home_page.dart--

```
return Material(
      child: Scaffold(

        drawer: Drawer,
        appBar: AppBarTheme,

          body:......
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i resolve' as prefix' in flutter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650216/how-do-i-resolve-as-prefix-in-flutter-error)

Comment: @Michael Horn
   I did that but still same error, Is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

In your import from the `flutter` sdk, you should `hide` the `AppBarTheme`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide AppBarTheme;

// rest of your file
```

Comment: I did that but still same error, Is there another way?

Comment: Are you importing anything from the flutter sdk?

Comment: yes, then I did like the way you told me and I heard about that the name 'AppBarTheme' is already defined in flutter so I changed name to MyAppBar and I imported the file that has MyAppBar and I used that like 'appbar: MyAppBar'.. but still it's errors..  @Apealed

Comment: You have to hide app bar theme from every import directive it come from (most flutter libraries have it)

Comment: Additionally this could all easily be "bypassed" if you name your class something else.

Comment: then, how can I resolve the error 'The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?' even though I made MyAppBar as preferredSizeWidget?  @Apealed

Comment: Please ask a different question. This is not you original question.

Comment: lofiu, its true for web3dart class incompatiblity with casue has the same function name.